# How to make method having executable block as a argument which should execute on completion of the method in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, objective-c-blocks

I want to define the method which will contain the block as an argument but block should be run on the `completion` of the method.

For Example:

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        imageThumb = pickedImage;
        imageViewThumb.image = imageThumb;


}];
```

Please have a look what i did yet.

I declared the method in `.h` file-

```
-(void)resizeImageForSmoothness: (int) imageSmoothness completion: (void (^)(void))completion;
```

I implemented it in `.m` file-

```
-(void)resizeImageForSmoothness:(int)imageSmoothness completion: (void (^)(void))completion
{

// Here i performed my image resizing activity  

}
```

How can my code will know that method has been completed and then run the completion block?

How can we declare and define such method?

Comment: BTW, I recommend you stick with Objective-C naming conventions. In this case, `ResizeImageForSmoothness` should start with a lower-case `r` instead. Usually, they start with lower-case letters except if the name starts with an abbreviation like `URLWithString:`.

Comment: Also, please reward the people who have helped you and accept more answers to your older questions. I've seen a few with valid answers that might/should get accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks DarkDust for your comment and Answer. it helps me, i always accept answer when i find any useful answer for me but i will remember your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to store the block depends on how you do your stuff. If it's a synchronous operation (that is, the method blocks until whole operation is complete) you simply call it like a function:

```
- (void)fooWithHandler:(void(^)())handler
{
    // Do things.
    handler();
}
```

If the operation is asynchronous, you might want to store the block in a variable or even a dictionary. In this case you need to *copy* the block. You can either do this via the low-level `Block_copy` and `Block_release` C functions, but you can also treat a block like an Objective-C object! (Xcode doesn't provide autocompletion for this, for some reason.)

```
@interface MyClass {
    void (^myHandler)();
}
- (void)fooWithHandler:(void(^)())handler
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (void)fooWithHandler:(void(^)())handler
{
    myHandler = [handler copy];
    // Do things.
    // Then, when you're done (this is probably in another method):
    if (myHandler) {
        myHandler();
        myHandler = nil;
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that and use the return type et parameter you might need :

```
- (void)doStuffAndExecute:(void (^)(void))handler
{
    // do stuff
    handler();
}
```